# Icon in notification

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Previously I thought that it's not possible to insert an icon in the push notification alert message, but somehow facebook does this, screenshot attached. So the question is how to insert an icon ? Sorry for bad quality of image.

[image: Notification with icon]

Comment: That's just the application icon.

Comment: You know that you can make screenshots by pressing the home + standby button, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just the application icon that is defined in the package.

It is identified by the application ID when setting up the APNS

Answer (score 0):

The layout and presentation of push notifications is defined by iOS you are able to supply an app icon that is always used with your push notifications (always the same) and the textual message. The icon you use must be based on the same app icon you use for the app itself. This is **part of the guidelines**.

Here is the reference for it

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/NotificationCenter.html